# Geoviews: Map Tile Overlaid With UK Choropleth Fails to Align Exactly

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh, choropleth, geoviews

I have a `~107K` row csv based off of the Office of National Statistics Postcode Lookup file which I loaded as DataFrame `df`.

(Please note that this link is for the original ONS file, not my altered one)

https://ons.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=4f71f3e9806d4ff895996f832eb7aacf

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import copy
import plotly.express as px
import panel as pn
import holoviews as hv
import geoviews as gv
import geoviews.feature as gf
import cartopy
import cartopy.feature as cf
from geoviews import opts
from cartopy import crs as ccrs

pn.extension("plotly")
gv.extension("bokeh")

df = pd.read_csv("../df_example_dataset_221119.csv")
```

### 1st 25 Rows of `df`:

```py
              nspl_easting  nspl_latitude nspl_localAuthorityDistrict  nspl_longitude  nspl_northing  ... postcode_prefix postcode_order                   supergroup                             group                                     subgroup
    0         205580      52.016209                   W06000009       -4.834655         239104  ...              SA            111                    Urbanites               Ageing urban living                   Self-sufficient retirement
    1         449021      51.740288                   E07000180       -1.291435         204857  ...              OX             91                    Urbanites               Ageing urban living                          Communal retirement
    2         443448      53.508308                   E08000018       -1.346353         401490  ...               S            119          Hard-pressed living           Industrious communities                      Industrious transitions
    3         415327      54.619576                   E06000047       -1.764161         524962  ...              DL             60          Hard-pressed living           Industrious communities                         Industrious hardship
    4         461888      52.962238                   E07000173       -1.080085         340937  ...              NG            115                    Urbanites  Urban professionals and families               Families in terraces and flats
    5         441508      50.915695                   E06000045       -1.410917         113080  ...              SO             89                Cosmopolitans            Students around campus                      Student communal living
    6         393588      52.553703                   E08000031       -2.096000         295100  ...              WV             43                 Suburbanites            Semi-detached suburbia                        Multi-ethnic suburbia
    7         440238      53.196899                   E07000038       -1.399148         366815  ...               S            119          Hard-pressed living           Industrious communities                         Industrious hardship
    8         197093      56.462948                   S12000035       -5.295074         734958  ...              PA             33              Rural residents                     Rural tenants                    Ageing rural flat tenants
    9         652748      52.603550                   E07000145        1.731206         307179  ...              NR            108  Multicultural metropolitans              Rented family living                 Private renting new arrivals
    10        443254      53.615883                   E08000036       -1.347626         413457  ...              WF             70                    Urbanites               Ageing urban living                   Self-sufficient retirement
    11        244584      52.002270                   W06000010       -4.265472         236183  ...              SA            111              Rural residents             Ageing rural dwellers                     Renting rural retirement
    12        342359      53.394840                   E08000012       -2.868276         389019  ...               L             93    Constrained city dwellers                 White communities                   Constrained young families
    13        317949      56.591812                   S12000048       -3.337703         745234  ...              PH             11    Constrained city dwellers              Challenged diversity  Transitional Eastern European neighbourhood
    14        522743      51.418400                   E09000024       -0.236223         170296  ...              SW             95                 Suburbanites                Suburban achievers                        Indian tech achievers
    15        416903      50.993282                   E06000054       -1.760528         121570  ...              SP             32              Rural residents                     Rural tenants                    Ageing rural flat tenants
    16        412438      53.683681                   E08000033       -1.813157         420819  ...              HX             13                    Urbanites               Ageing urban living                   Self-sufficient retirement
    17        380633      53.561138                   E08000002       -2.293852         407209  ...              BL             45                    Urbanites               Ageing urban living                           Delayed retirement
    18        465475      50.795639                   E06000044       -1.072351          99975  ...              PO            112  Multicultural metropolitans              Rented family living                 Private renting new arrivals
    19        525069      51.103195                   E07000226       -0.215022         135281  ...              RH             74  Multicultural metropolitans              Rented family living                Social renting young families
    20        324536      55.648670                   S12000026       -3.200686         640113  ...              EH            110                 Suburbanites                Suburban achievers                           Ageing in suburbia
    21        317378      54.844311                   E07000026       -3.288153         550704  ...              CA             58              Rural residents                     Rural tenants                                   Rural life
    22        491761      51.034000                   E07000225       -0.692730         126884  ...              GU            104              Rural residents               Farming communities                     Agricultural communities
    23        449460      54.650303                   E06000001       -1.234992         528624  ...              TS             81                 Suburbanites            Semi-detached suburbia                         Semi-detached ageing
    24        457016      52.624683                   E06000016       -1.159144         303321  ...              LE            103  Multicultural metropolitans              Rented family living                 Private renting new arrivals
```

### Data Types:

```py
    In [35]: df.info()                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    RangeIndex: 107632 entries, 0 to 107631
    Data columns (total 14 columns):
    nspl_easting                                 107632 non-null int32
    nspl_latitude                                107632 non-null float32
    nspl_localAuthorityDistrict                  107632 non-null category
    nspl_longitude                               107632 non-null float32
    nspl_northing                                107632 non-null int32
    nspl_outputAreaClassification                107632 non-null category
    nspl_ward                                    107632 non-null category
    nspl_westminsterParliamentaryConstituency    107632 non-null category
    postcode                                     107632 non-null object
    postcode_prefix                              107632 non-null category
    postcode_order                               107632 non-null int32
    supergroup                                   107632 non-null category
    group                                        107632 non-null category
    subgroup                                     107632 non-null category
    dtypes: category(8), float32(2), int32(3), object(1)
    memory usage: 4.4+ MB
```

The `postcode_prefix` column contains all 121 UK postcode areas.

```py
In [50]: df["postcode_prefix"].value_counts()                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[50]: 
BT    2978
B     2625
S     2099
M     1988
NE    1975
      ... 
WC     165
LD     140
KW     108
HS      53
ZE      30
Name: postcode_prefix, Length: 121, dtype: int64
```

While the `postcode_order` column contains numbers 1 - 121. 1 = lowest count of `postcode_prefix` in `df` (`ie ZE`), 121 = highest count (`ie BT`) in `df`.

```py
In [42]: df["postcode_order"].value_counts()                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[42]: 
121    2978
120    2625
119    2099
118    1988
117    1975
       ... 
5       165
4       140
3       108
2        53
1        30
Name: postcode_order, Length: 121, dtype: int64
```

### UK Shapefile downloaded from:

https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/bbb0e58b0be64cc1a1460aa69e33678f_0/data

```py
shapefile = "../Local_Authority_Districts_April_2019_Boundaries_UK_BUC/Local_Authority_Districts_April_2019_Boundaries_UK_BUC.shp"
gv.Shape.from_shapefile(shapefile, crs=ccrs.Mercator())
```

```py
In [51]: shapes = cartopy.io.shapereader.Reader(shapefile) 
    ...: list(shapes.records())[0]                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[51]: <Record: <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x1c35f30a50>, {'objectid': 1, 'lad19cd': 'E06000001', 'lad19nm': 'Hartlepool', 'lad19nmw': None, 'bng_e': 447157, 'bng_n': 531476, 'long': -1.27023005, 'lat': 54.67620087, 'st_areasha': 96512310.88728464, 'st_lengths': 50488.38708066442}, <fields>>
```

### Set Latitude and Longitude and plot choropleth

```py
heatmap = gv.Shape.from_records(shapes.records(), df, on={"lad19cd":"nspl_localAuthorityDistrict"}, value="postcode_order",
                      index=["postcode_prefix","nspl_outputAreaClassification","supergroup","group","subgroup"], crs=ccrs.Orthographic(central_longitude=-8.00, central_latitude=50.00)).opts(tools=["hover"], cmap = "Reds", colorbar=True, title="UK Postcode Heatmap", width=800, height=1350, alpha=0.4)
heatmap
```

### Set Map Tile

```py
wikimap =hv.Tiles('https://maps.wikimedia.org/osm-intl/{Z}/{X}/{Y}@2x.png', name="Wikipedia").opts(width=800, height=1350)
```

### Final plot, including setting a point marker (latitude and longitude used here is for Big Ben)

```py
wikimap * heatmap * gv.Points([(-0.116773,51.510357)]).opts(color='purple', size = 20)
```

## **Resultant Plot**:

As you can see below, my choropleth very nearly overlays successfully over the map tile. However no matter how much I tweak the `central_longitude` and `central_latitude` values, I can't get them to line up exactly. It actually seems like I need to rotate my choropleth slightly some how.

[image]

I suspect that my issue is caused by either:

**1. The shapefile that I am using**

or

**2. The projections that I have chosen**

I tried to make both projections equal `crs=ccrs.Mercator()`, however this does not allow me to set the `latitude` and `longitude` for  my choropleth thus preventing successfully overlaying this with the map tile.

Any pointers in the right direction would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: this really looks like a projection problem to me ...

Comment: Since posting this question I did a bit more research and found this link: scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/crs/projections.html 

Here I found projection = OSGB - switching to this resulted in my desired choropleth successfully being overlaid on top of my map tile. Please see my answer for this question as I can't add the result to this comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update on 23/11/19:

After posting this question I found:
https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/crs/projections.html

Here I found projection = OSGB. Switching to this projection resulted in my desired result:

[image]